# Webfont looks horrible in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, font-face

I'm working on getting Museo Slab 500 font to display similar across all browsers.

The only browser where I can not get the font to work properly is Firefox. In fact, the font looks horrible. Especially notice the "w".

Example: [image]

What I did: Downloaded font from: myfonts.com and
generated webfont at: fontsquirrel.com

OS:  Widows 8

Firefox version: 21.0

CSS:

```
@font-face {  
    font-family: 'museo_slab500';

    src: url('../font/exljbris_-_museoslab-500-webfont.eot');

    src:url('../font/exljbris_-_museoslab-500-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../font/exljbris_-_museoslab-500-webfont.svg#museo_slab500') format('svg'),
    url('../font/exljbris_-_museoslab-500-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../font/exljbris_-_museoslab-500-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');

    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {

    @font-face {
        font-family: 'museo_slab500';
        src: url('../font/exljbris_-_museoslab-500-webfont.svg#museo_slab500') format('svg');

        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;

    }
}
```

What can I do? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Provide a link where you have this issue.

Comment: provide a demo for this...

Comment: Thank you for looking into this: http://creativekick.dk/example/example.html

Comment: It seems that it was fixed so that it matches in Chrome. It seems to me that people select this font because of the bleeding w. One site for laundry detergent seemed to choose it for that reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-rendering
And try differents value of text-rendering. Maybe nothing will change, but sometimes it helps.

Have you tried on another computer ? Because the text rendering can change between differents computers and/or OS.

Comment: I'm on firefox 21 (Max OS X) and it looks fine. What OS are you using ? If it's windows, maybe check the cleartype options in admin panel

Comment: You can also try  to disable the firefox hardware acceleration.
(tools > Options > Advanced > General > Browsing: "Use hardware acceleration when available" )
Or update your graphic card drivers.

Comment: Thank you FC Reseting Windows 8 system fontsettings solved it. Thank you tried all day to make it work :-). How do I mark an answer as "The solution"?

Comment: I don't remember, i think there is a button below upvote/downvote

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem after I changed my graphic card. Updating drivers did not help, looks like somehow Firefox disabled DirectWrite feature. To manually enable this feature open `about:config`, than check if `gfx.font_rendering.directwrite.enabled` property. Double click to set it **true** (in case it is false).

[image: Firefox gfx.font_rendering.directwrite.enabled set to true]

Restart Firefox after.